# Spring Boot manipulate http parameters on runtime

Tags: rest, spring-boot, spring-mvc, java-8, interceptor

I'm trying, without success, to manipulate some http parameters (in query, body ...) before the call is received by the final endpoint. For example, we have this post call:

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8080/insertBody/" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Date-Format: yyyy-MM-dd" -d "{ \"isUniform\": true, \"myDate\": \"2020-01-14T08:55:07.013Z\", \"myInt\": 0, \"uniform\": true}"
```

What I'm trying to do is converting **myDate -> 2020-01-14T08:55:07.013Z** inside the post body in this format **yyyy-MM-dd** passed in the header. The manipulation has to involve all objects of type **OffsetDateTime** (in this case) present in this call.

When the call is received by the microservice:

```
Header:
  Date-Format: yyyy-MM-dd
Body
  {
    "isUniform": true,
    "myDate": "2020-01-14T08:55:07.013Z",
    "myInt": 0,
    "uniform": true
  }
```

After data manipulation and what is received by the controller:

```
Header:
  Date-Format: yyyy-MM-dd
Body
  {
    "isUniform": true,
    "myDate": "2020-01-14",   <---
    "myInt": 0,
    "uniform": true
  }
```

Body class

```
public class CashBackCampaignRequest   {

  @JsonProperty("uniform")
  private Boolean uniform = true;

  @JsonProperty("myInt")
  private Integer myInt = null;

  @JsonProperty("myDate")
  private OffsetDateTime myDate = null;

  // getter setters ...
}
```

Comment: Could you please post your `myDate` field of your `entity`? looks like you format it as `date` `yyyy-MM-dd`

Comment: Thanks for responding. Don't focus on the datetime conversation, what I want is to perform some specific operation on ALL the object types. Example: find all String and add a space in the end @Oneguy

Comment: Add on head `@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm")`

Comment: no, I need it dynamic, the format is passed in the header, every time is different @Oneguy

Answer (score 1):

You should use the famous `RequestBodyAdviceAdapter`. You can, before entering your controller, manipulate the body of your message. You declare a `@ControllerAdvice` or `@RestControllerAdvice` (it is just a `@Component`), and extends the class `RequestBodyAdviceAdapter`. (you can also implements the interface `RequestBodyAdvice`, but I'd recommend extending the abstract class).

Here is a quick example:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class WebAdvice extends RequestBodyAdviceAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter methodParameter, Type type, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> aClass) {
        // to know whether you will use your advice or not
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object afterBodyRead(Object body, HttpInputMessage inputMessage, MethodParameter parameter, Type targetType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        String format = inputMessage.getHeaders().get("DATE_FORMAT").get(0);
        if(body instanceof CashBackCampaignRequest) {
            // Do whatever you want
            ((CashBackCampaignRequest) body).setDate()
        }
        return super.afterBodyRead(body, inputMessage, parameter, targetType, converterType);
    }
}
```

Be careful with the type of the request received in the `Controller`. If your controller receives an object of type `CashBackCampaignRequest`, then you won't be able to change the format.

Answer (score 0):

Based on RUARDO answere I canged **RequestBodyAdviceAdapter** with **ResponseBodyAdvice< Object>**

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ResponseJsonFilterAdvice implements ResponseBodyAdvice<Object> {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter returnType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        // true if want to use this controller
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object beforeBodyWrite(
            Object body, 
            MethodParameter returnType, 
            MediaType selectedContentType,
            Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> selectedConverterType, 
            ServerHttpRequest request,
            ServerHttpResponse response) {

        List<String> headers = request.getHeaders().get("X-MY-DATE-FORMAT");
        if(headers == null || headers.isEmpty())
            return body;


        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());  
        SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();
        simpleModule.addSerializer(OffsetDateTime.class, new JsonSerializer<OffsetDateTime>() {
            @Override
            public void serialize(OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
                jsonGenerator.writeString(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(headers.get(0)).format(offsetDateTime));
            }
        });
        objectMapper.registerModule(simpleModule);

        try {
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(body);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return body;
    }
}
```